# Using Get-StoredCredential function in VS Code

Tags: powershell, vscode-extensions

I use a Get-StoredCredential function in my Powershell ISE profile to authenticate the various modules I use, which avoids the need for authentication prompts when loading PS modules

I would now like to start using VS Code with the PS extension as my primary script editor, instead of PS ISE.

When I try and load my profile script into VS Code however, the process errors when trying to execute the portion of the script that authenticates the modules.

The Get-StoredCredential function runs successfully, however it would appear that the modules in the script do not like being passed the .cred files

For example:

when the following portion of the script is run, an error is displayed:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nztoP.png)

I guess what I could do to know is:

- is the use of stored credentials via .cred files supported in VS Code?
- if so is there a workaround to be able to authenticate against the various MS online modules?
- Is the issue with the modules, VS Code, the PS extension or all 3?

I'm very new to VS Code so apologies in advance for any noobness

Thanks

ran the functions below in isolation - the Get-StoredCredential -List successfully lists the stored creds once executed.

```
$keypath = 'C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Keys'

Function New-StoredCredential {
    
    if (!(Test-Path Variable:\KeyPath)) {
        Write-Warning "The `$KeyPath variable has not been set. Consider adding `$KeyPath to your PowerShell profile to avoid this prompt."
        $path = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a path for stored credentials"
        Set-Variable -Name KeyPath -Scope Global -Value $path

        if (!(Test-Path $KeyPath)) {
        
            try {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $KeyPath -ErrorAction STOP | Out-Null
            }
            catch {
                throw $_.Exception.Message
            }           
        }
    }

    $Credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter a user name and password"

    $Credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "$($KeyPath)\$($Credential.Username).cred" -Force

}


Function Get-StoredCredential {
 

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="Get")]
        [string]$UserName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="List")]
        [switch]$List
        )

    if (!(Test-Path Variable:\KeyPath)) {
        Write-Warning "The `$KeyPath variable has not been set. Consider adding `$KeyPath to your PowerShell profile to avoid this prompt."
        $path = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a path for stored credentials"
        Set-Variable -Name KeyPath -Scope Global -Value $path
    }


    if ($List) {

        try {
        $CredentialList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $keypath -Filter *.cred -ErrorAction STOP)

        foreach ($Cred in $CredentialList) {
            Write-Host "Username: $($Cred.BaseName)"
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
        }

    }

    if ($UserName) {
        if (Test-Path "$($KeyPath)\$($Username).cred") {
        
            $PwdSecureString = Get-Content "$($KeyPath)\$($Username).cred" | ConvertTo-SecureString
            
            $Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $PwdSecureString
        }
        else {
            throw "Unable to locate a credential for $($Username)"
        }

        return $Credential
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `$cred = Get-Credential;
$cred.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\Folder\path\file.ext";` to create and `$SecurePassword = Get-Content "C:\Folder\path\file.ext" | ConvertTo-SecureString;
 $UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecurePassword;`. You're saying the same there that works with PowerShell ISE does not work in VSCode. The file extension doesn't have to be a .cred to work, just the content of the file needs to be decrypted by the same user on the same machine it was created.

Comment: No - I'm using the "New-StoredCredential" and "Get-StoredCredential" functions as per the above. In reality, only the "Get-StoredCredential" is used as the .cred files are already in place on the local machine, and can be queried using the Get-StoredCredential -List cmdlet in VSCode, using the PS extension.

Only when the profile script is run, the reading of the credentials fails, when attempting to authenticate the MS modules in the script, as per the "example" image above.

Comment: Those function appear to likely do those things I mentioned just wrapped in a function. In any event, based on image screen shot, it looks like your credential file with the encrypted password value is being returned NULL so with no value. I'd break the logic out of the functions and start running it line by line until you find the problem. Incorporate the fix so the value is not NULL back into the function logic. It is saying the password value it NULL and it cannot be via `New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecurePassword`confirm variable names too.